# A configuration error occurs when running the tomcat server in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, tomcat8

The path clearly exists, but I don't know why the FileNotFoundException error occurs.

I don't know why the creation threw exception error occurs even though I've checked that the class file is loading properly.

I don't understand why the characters are broken even though I set the encoding method of logging.properties to the method of my region.

```
Configuration error
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 'c:\Users\user\.rsp\redhat-community-server-connector\runtimes\installations\apache-tomcat-8.5.87\conf\logging.properties' (���� �̸�, ���͸� �̸� �Ǵ� ���� ���̺� ������ �߸��Ǿ����ϴ�)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:158)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:483)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:321)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:446)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:395)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:383)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:431)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:650)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:720)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:703)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:61)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:181)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:130)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:153)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
3�� 05, 2023 6:03:41 ���� org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap initClassLoaders
SEVERE: Class loader creation threw exception
java.io.IOException: ���� �̸�, ���͸� �̸� �Ǵ� ���� ���̺� ������ �߸��Ǿ����ϴ�
    at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:465)
    at java.base/java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:626)
    at java.base/java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:179)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.createClassLoader(Bootstrap.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.initClassLoaders(Bootstrap.java:146)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:447)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have updated my plugin: Community Server Connector v0.26.3  I also encountered the same problem.
This is solution:delete the old tomcat,and roll back the plugin version to v0.25.7 and create a new tomcat

Comment: about characters  broken. I set the encoding method of vscode. and it's ok

Comment: thank you so much.
i was resolved that tomcat server run
and fixed borken character.

Answer (score 0):

rollback the community server connector to version 0.26.3. Tomcat also broke, but a rollback helped.

Comment: Thank you for answer
But it has nothing to do with community server connector version
The current version is 0.26.3